# Jami Android - error when build iconv lib

Tags: android, linux

follow here https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/ring-project to build Jami android but I face this error when build client-android

```
libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/libiconv.a .libs/libiconv.la .libs/libiconv.lai libtool: link: ar cru .libs/libiconv.a  objects/iconv.o objects/localcharset.o objects/relocatable.o 
ar: u modifier ignored since D is the default (see U) 
libtool: link: /home/tan111/devtools/android-ndk-r21e/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ranlib .libs/libiconv.a 
libtool: link: ( cd ".libs" && rm -f "libiconv.la" && ln -s "../libiconv.la" "libiconv.la" ) 
cp .libs/libiconv.so preloadable_libiconv.so 
cp: cannot stat .libs/libiconv.so': No such file or directory 
make[2]: *** [Makefile:52: preloadable_libiconv.so] Error 1 make[2]: Leaving directory /home/tan111/jami/ring-project/daemon/contrib/native-aarch64-linux-android/iconv/preload
make[1]: *** [Makefile:49: install] Error 2 make[1]: Leaving directory /home/tan111/jami/ring-project/daemon/contrib/native-aarch64-linux-android/iconv 
make: *** [/home/tan111/jami/ring-project/daemon/contrib/src/iconv/rules.mak:41: .iconv] Error 2
```

Does anyone facing it before? Please help me
Thank a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try to set `ar` to the ndk, like this:

`make AR=/home/tan111/devtools/android-ndk-r21e/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/llvm-ar -j4`